# Android LogCat Error Videos and Images

Tags: android, xamarin, logcat

i show on my tablelayout two videos and two images. For the videos i use the VideoView and for the images i use Picasso. All code is writed with Xamarin Android.
After any hours i have this error in logcat, but i don't understand the problem.

Can someone help me ? Sorry for my english.

```
07-28 13:47:35.090: E/Surface(2313): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
07-28 13:47:35.090: E/Surface(2313): queueBuffer (handle=0x6a578a80) failed (No such device)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313): Could not unlock surface
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.Surface.nativeUnlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Surface.java:285)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2584)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2437)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2281)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1005)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5750)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
07-28 13:47:35.110: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 13:47:35.130: E/ViewRootImpl(2313):                 drawSoftware()            getRotation()  error~~~@!    
07-28 13:47:37.220: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(2313): media server died
07-28 13:47:37.220: E/MediaPlayer(2313): error (100, 0)
07-28 13:47:37.220: W/AudioSystem(2313): AudioFlinger server died!
07-28 13:47:37.220: E/MediaPlayer(2313): error (100, 0)
07-28 13:47:37.220: E/MediaPlayer(2313): Error (100,0)
07-28 13:47:37.220: D/VideoView(2313): Error: 100,0
07-28 13:47:37.300: D/AndroidRuntime(2313): Shutting down VM
07-28 13:47:37.300: W/dalvikvm(2313): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418e22a0)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): Process: com.XXX.XXX, PID: 2313
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:516)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.widget.VideoView$5.onError(VideoView.java:515)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2248)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:721)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:505)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     ... 14 more
07-28 13:47:37.330: I/Process(2313): Sending signal. PID: 2313 SIG: 9
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): Error reporting crash
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313): android.os.DeadObjectException
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:3703)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:84)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.runtime.UncaughtExceptionHandler.n_uncaughtException(Native Method)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at android.runtime.UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(UncaughtExceptionHandler.java:37)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
07-28 13:47:37.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2313):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you describe when you run into this issue? Do you go off the main screen at anytime and then come back? Have you ensured you are releasing Resources appropriately?

Comment: No the application run on the screen not in background. For releasing resources, i have call the dispose